# How to count words which overlap with each other seperatedly in a text file

Tags: c, function, search, text-files

I am searching in a txt file that the user has chosen to find
    specific words and symbols (&) , that are already defined by the
    library. I have done a separated function for each word ( because I
    don't really know how to combine them) but I cant figure out the
    do/while search function.

I have done a separated function for each word, but I cant figure out the do/while search function in essence the problem I
    have is whit the combining the functions and searching for a 2 part
    word and only. I want to count while and do/while separated.

```
 #include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < string.h >
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

/* Function declarations. How do I combine them all? */
int CountOccurrences ( FILE *fptr, char *word );

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr; // name

    SetConsoleCP (1251); // so that it runs with my language 
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);

    char path[100];

    // The 4 words and the symbol I am searching for.

    char word[]= "while";
    char word1[]= "for";
    char word2[]= "&";
    char word3[]= "do{ }while";

    int wCount; // Variable to get the value of the function.
    int wCount1; // same 
    int wCount2; // same 
    int wCount3; // same 

    /* Input file path */
    printf ( "Enter file path: " );
    scanf ( "%s", path );

    /* Try to open file */
    fptr = fopen ( path, "r" );

    /* Exit if file not opened successfully */
    if ( fptr == NULL )
    {
        printf ( "Unable to open file.\n" ); //Error msg
        printf ( "Please check you have read/write previleges.\n" ); //Help msg

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //end
    }

     // Call function to count all occurrence of word
    wCount = CountOccurrences ( fptr, word );
     //rewind so I can use It again

    rewind ( fptr );
    printf ( "'%s' is found %d times in file.\n", word, wCount );

    //the method is the same for all the 4 functions        
    fclose ( fptr ); //close file

    return 0;  /* How can I search for overlapping words in a txt file with the goal to differentiate from each other in a txt file */ 
}

 //Returns total occurrences of a word in given file.
 int CountOccurrences(FILE *fptr, char *word) {

    char str [BUFFER_SIZE]; //The other functions are the same
    char *pos;

    int index, count;

    //make a variable to count the amount of occurrences 

    count = 0;

    // Read line from file till end of file.
    while ((fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, fptr)) != NULL)
    {
        index = 0; //to store the word

        // Find next occurrence of word in str
        while ((pos = strstr(str + index, word)) != NULL)
        {
            index = (pos - str) + 1;

             // Index of word in str is
             // Memory address of pos - memory
             // address of str.

            count++; // sums every time for a specific word
        }
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: FWIW you don't need write privileges to read files.  if you use `perror("Unable to open file")`, your error message will include a (terse) error message as to what failed.  Your help msg only really applies if it was EACCESS, permission denied.

Comment: I would like to make the question clear. Do you want to count "while( ){ ... }" and "do{...}while( )" separately in C/C++ source code?

Comment: @Shu Suzuki Yes I want to count the occurrences of the words "while" and "do{..}while() " separately from a text file. I am having trouble to figure out the search function for "do while" without it counting the word "while" and adding it onto the "do/while" function.

Comment: @Peter So how general do you want to search it. I thinks if you want to count real "while" and "do ... while" you have to make C parser. I assume that your target text file is C source file. C source file can contain string literals like `char *text = "this is for(...)";`. If you are searching this text file for "for", you will count this too but this is not "for" as C language but just text string. The same thing also happens to "while". You also need to consider if while is nested or other complex patterns. What level of text searching do you need?

Comment: @ShuSuzuki Yeah, I should have explained it better. I am searching for it just as a text string. But I figured it out, it was really simple, count the amount of times "do" appears , and the amount of times "while" appears and match them both, the rest is the number of times "while" is counted.

Answer (score 0):

In CountOccurances() function in below while loop, using strcmp() for each of word1, word2, word3 and word4, it is possible to find words.

```
  while ((pos = strstr(str + index, word))
```

Further in fgets() function, newline will be read at the end of word read which can cause strcmp() to fail. It can be handled by making last character of word minus 1 to be null